# Modeling domain type

Tags: f#

A limit price has a decimal value. A Market price does not.

How do I model this in F#?

```
module TradingDomain

let NoPrice = None

type PriceActionType = 
    | Limit of decimal
    | Market of NoPrice
```

Comment: Strictly speaking a market price also has a decimal value, and it's higher than the current price if you're buying and lower than the current price if you're selling. Some markets will model market price as a limit price by setting it like the above, others will set it at the daily limit. And when the order is executed you will get back a weighted average price, a decimal. How does your Market model the market price? I.e. what do you send to execute a market order? A price of 0.? A string, a null, etc? Market of decimal, Market of None (basically an Option value), Market are all possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just not give `Market` any arguments:

```
type PriceActionType =
    | Limit of decimal
    | Market
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to go about it, but if you do domain modelling it's a good idea to have an understanding of all the components, in this case, 1) how traders think about the order, 2) how FIX (if that's what's being used) thinks about the order, and 3) how the market you trade thinks about the order. Btw, there's this [book](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/f-quantitative-finance/) that you might find useful. Also, [Chapter 7](https://github.com/dmitry-a-morozov/DeepDives) in F# Deep Dives.

That said Tarmil's answer should work for you, and here but I have two comments. Sometimes it's better to be explicit about the type and use .NET types. `float` and `decimal` are F# aliases and they might refer to the function that casts to float. There is also the possibility to use Some and None for expressing the price. So here's a version that includes the orderside as well:

```
type Price =
    | Limit of Decimal
    | Market

type OrderSide =
    | Buy of Price
    | Sell of Price 
    | ShortSell of Price
```

You can use it like this: `Buy (Limit 10.0M)` or `Sell Market`.
You could also define Price like this:

```
type Price2 =
    | Limit of Decimal option
    | None
```

Whichever version will help you later do validation.